# Передача данных из разных input в одной строке

Tags: php

Например есть форма с такими полями для ввода: "Название", "Цена", "Описание". "Описание" в свою очередь состоит из input'ов "Название параметра 1" и "Значение 1". После заполнение этих двух полей необходимо по нажатию кнопки создавать ещё одну строку с полями "Название параметра 2" и "Значение 2" и так далее. С созданием ещё одной строки проблем пока что вроде нет, но как передать значение в виде "Название параметра 1=Значение 1;Название параметра 2=Значение 2;..."?

Comment: Так и передавайте <input type="text" name="param[1]" value="значение 1"> далее <input type="text" name="param[2]" value="значение "> далее <input type="text" name="param[3]" value="значение 3"> и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указывайте в качестве имени поля массив:

```
<input name="params[]" value="значение параметра 1" />
<input name="params[]" value="значение параметра 2" />
...
<input name="params[]" value="значение параметра N" />
```

В `php` получаете массив: `$_POST['params']`

Comment: Я немножко неправильно наверное объяснил... `<input type="text" name="var_name1" placeholder="Название параметра"><input type="text" name="val1" placeholder="Значение"><input type="text" name="var_name2" placeholder="Название параметра"><input type="text" name="val2" placeholder="Значение"> и т.д.` Потом эти все данные надо записать в одну ячейку БД

Comment: В принципе по вашему примеру должно получиться, сейчас попробую